# How do I use disk animals in combat?

Tags: kamen-rider-hibiki

Sometimes while fighting in Kamen Rider Hibiki for PS2, a [disk animal](https://kamenrider.fandom.com/wiki/Disk_Animals) will appear in the top left or top right corner of the screen. It usually shows up a few seconds after a round starts.

What makes the disk animal icon appear? How do I use disk animals in combat?

[image]